# Include plugin form in the home page

Tags: plugins, database, forms

I created a Wordpress plugin, which allows the admin to add information through a form, and it is saved in the database. I'm trying to link each photo that I upload in the Media library with a form.

In other words, my objective is that I want to put my own caption in each image of the Media library, and this caption is taken through a form.

So I have the data from the form fields in a table in my db and another table with the media pictures. How can I link them between each other?

Does anyone have an idea about what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the images are posts. Register a new post meta for them and use the ID for your form in that post meta, this will allow you to relate to the form.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta